# Setting title and border for series of Articles

Tags: html, css, node.js, vue.js

I am displaying a series of articles from a RSS Feed on my Vue.js application.

I am trying to put the following articles in a container (similar to the tweets on the left) with a heading called *Latest Articles*. When I include a  tag in the template section, the h1 is displayed for each article which I do not want. How do I overcome this? Am I better off using bootstrap?

My code:

```vue
<template>
    <div class="Articles">
        <a :href="feed.link">{{feed.title}}</a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ["feed"]
    }
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you generating elements out of you're database its mostly through a loop. So make sure you put the header h1  out of the loop. Otherwise the loop will print the statement all over again.

If you want to set a border you can just make an extra id or class in youre css or with the  tag in you're html and add it to you're

.class or #id {border:  solid black 3px} for example